# I need get the event when I calling someone,the event for me,The most important is the ringback event

Tags: android

The first:

What is the ringback:When I called someone.My phone connected the other's,play some voice in earphone,The voice  is the ringbacktone.

Some Classes bound of ringback.

PATH:

com.android.server.telecom.RingbackPlayer;

com.android.server.telecom.CallAudioManager;

com.android.server.telecom.CallsManager;

The player initialization in CallsManager's Constructor with full params;

PATH:

com.android.server.telecom.CallsManager;

LINE:545

Code:

```
mCallAudioManager = new CallAudioManager(callAudioRouteStateMachine,
                this, callAudioModeStateMachineFactory.create(systemStateHelper,
                (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)),
                playerFactory, mRinger, new RingbackPlayer(playerFactory),
                bluetoothStateReceiver, mDtmfLocalTonePlayer);
```

The event of ringback:

LINE:741

CODE:

```
private void playToneForDisconnectedCall(Call call) {
    // If this call is being disconnected as a result of being handed over to another call,
    // we will not play a disconnect tone.
    if (call.isHandoverInProgress()) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Omitting tone because %s is being handed over.", call);
        return;
    }
    if (mForegroundCall != null && call != mForegroundCall && mCalls.size() > 1) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Omitting tone because we are not foreground" +
                " and there is another call.");
        return;
    }
    if (call.getDisconnectCause() != null) {
        int toneToPlay = InCallTonePlayer.TONE_INVALID;
        Log.v(this, "Disconnect cause: %s.", call.getDisconnectCause());
        switch(call.getDisconnectCause().getTone()) {
            case ToneGenerator.TONE_SUP_BUSY:
                toneToPlay = InCallTonePlayer.TONE_BUSY;
                break;
            case ToneGenerator.TONE_SUP_CONGESTION:
                toneToPlay = InCallTonePlayer.TONE_CONGESTION;
                break;
            case ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_REORDER:
                toneToPlay = InCallTonePlayer.TONE_REORDER;
                break;
            case ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ABBR_INTERCEPT:
                toneToPlay = InCallTonePlayer.TONE_INTERCEPT;
                break;
            case ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_CALLDROP_LITE:
                toneToPlay = InCallTonePlayer.TONE_CDMA_DROP;
                break;
            case ToneGenerator.TONE_SUP_ERROR:
                toneToPlay = InCallTonePlayer.TONE_UNOBTAINABLE_NUMBER;
                break;
            case ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_PROMPT:
                toneToPlay = InCallTonePlayer.TONE_CALL_ENDED;
                break;
        }
        Log.d(this, "Found a disconnected call with tone to play %d.", toneToPlay);
        if (toneToPlay != InCallTonePlayer.TONE_INVALID) {
            boolean didToneStart = mPlayerFactory.createPlayer(toneToPlay).startTone();
            if (didToneStart) {
                mCallsManager.onDisconnectedTonePlaying(true);
                mIsDisconnectedTonePlaying = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So.We should can get the event in any application when as a default dialer application.

My application is the default application of the device when user installed.
I implement the InCallService in My application

```
public void onCallAdded(Call call) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCallAdded: ");
        super.onCallAdded(call);
        if (nowCall == null) {
            nowCall = call;
            nowCall.registerCallback(nowCallback = AbstractCallback.create(nowCall, null, this));
            firstCall(nowCall, nowCallback);
        } else {
            call.registerCallback(callback = AbstractCallback.create(call, nowCall, this));
            firstCall(call, callback);
        }
```

I proxy the mHandler in my InCallService.

CODE:

```
public static void proxyInCallHandler(InCallService inCallService) {
        Field mHandler = ReflectSystem.field(InCallService.class, "mHandler");
        try {
            Handler o = (Handler) mHandler.get(inCallService);
            InCallServiceHandler proxy = InCallServiceHandler.proxy(o);
            mHandler.set(inCallService,o);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But only the CONNECTING、CONNECTED、DIALING、RINGING、ACTIVE、DISCONNECTING、DISCONNECTED events handled the Message.Have none ringback event in it.

How  can I get it.

I tried:

Reflect the ITelephony,check the state in loop for all of method in it when returned boolean.

Reflect the ITelecom,check the state in loop for all of method in it when returned boolean.

Reflect the AudioManager and IAudioService$Binder.Check all stream state in loop .

Check all state in TelecomManager and TelephonyManager in loop.

Ohh.  I have none ideas.  Help me please